# Find a Nash equilibrium solver

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

The solvers I know so far are designed only to allow payoffs as given numbers.
But is there a solver allowing users to type payoffs as variables?

Comment: Question too imprecise and vague. What do you mean by "type payoffs as variables" ?

Comment: Yes. Since the solvers I found so far only accept given numbers as payoff inputs, I wonder if there is a solver that can type variables as payoff inputs  to see how Nash equilibria perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I am aware of. You could always write a script that generates instances of a parametrically defined game for an existing solver and then do a parameter sweep. For more than two players, even describing the set of equilibria for a given game (with all payoffs specified as actual numbers) is highly non-trivial, and given the state-of-the-art what you are asking for is rather unrealistic (except maybe for very small games).

Comment: Oh yes, that is what I am doing now. It seems python is a better choice to apply than matlab if I use Gambit as the solver. Thank you for your information. It is good to know the computational aspect of Nash equilibrium.

Comment: Python is certainly a  good choice, especially with Gambit. How many players do your games have?

Comment: Just two. So I guess it is simpler than the general case in which n players are involved.

Comment: Then you can and should use exact arithmetic. Gambit should be fine. Gambit can use lrslis with the -L flag, but I am not sure who widely tested this is. Any problems, then you could also use lrs directly, see  http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/C/lrslib/USERGUIDE.html#nash and this other answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881906/computer-software-for-solving-mixed-strategy-nash-equilibrium